# What happened to 'Format' function in VS 2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, format

I am not able to use `Format function` in a converted VB2008 project in VS 2010.

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59bz1f0h%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) about `Format function` in not available for VS 2010.

Has that function been deprecated? If so, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [`Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.format.aspx) documentation for Visual Studio 2010.

And a link to the index of [String Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789093.aspx) in Visual Basic.

Microsoft moved things around, as they do on occasion, which makes finding the latest documentation somewhat harder.